# Why typeof 1===1 returns false instead of boolean

Tags: javascript

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) website if you look at `typeof operand`
**Def:** operand is an expression representing the object or primitive
we know that `1===1 // returns true` it is a primitive type `boolean` and
`typeof true // always returns boolean`

But when i run below code

```js
console.log(typeof 1===1);
```

I don't understand why it returns `false` instead of `boolean`

Comment: you are comparing the string of the `type` to `1`. That's not going to be equal ever, since `1` is a `number`.

Comment: typeof has higher precedence over comparison

Comment: because `===` is a strict comparison of the value. `typeof 1` is "number" so you are strictly comparing the string value "number" to the numerical value 1

Comment: @Kinduser sorry for that, i did it because Alex first answered it has to do with operator precedence before you modified your answer as pointed out by Vincent

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`typeof` operator has higher *precedence* than `===`, hence the expression **`typeof 1===1` is interpreted as `(typeof 1)===1`**:

- The `typeof` operator returns a string; `(typeof 1)` evaluates to the string `'number'`.
- `'number' === 1` evaluates to `false` for obvious reasons.

See [MDN atricle on operator precedence in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

---

As another example, by analogy, `typeof 1+1` results in the string `'number1'`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out....

Answer (score 37):

Since the [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator comes with a higher precedence then `===`:

- The first operation is actually `typeof 1` which returns a `"number"`.
- The next operation is `"number" === 1`, which return false, because **obviously** a `string` isn't a `number`.

If you want to make it work, use parentheses inside to process the comparison `(1 === 1)` **first** and **then** check its type.

```js
console.log(typeof (1 === 1));
```

**More info**: **[MDN Operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)**.

Comment: Just for clarification, "Javascript reads code from left to right" is slightly misleading. This has to do with operator precedence, as other answers point out. Obviously, `4 + 5 * 6` returns `34` as expected and not `54`.

Comment: No, [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) is an operator, just like `+` or `*`. It happens that the precedence of `typeof` is higher than that of `===`, so it is executed first. `1 === typeof 1` would exhibit the same behaviour. You can look on the [Operator precedence page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) on the MDN to convince yourself.

Answer (score 6):

The expression is evaluated as `(typeof 1)===1`, due to *operator precedence*. And that is not `true`.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use

```
console.log(typeof (1 === 1));
```